# Unlocking the Galaxy S5?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

Stock firmware does not do for unlocking a locked Samsung Galaxy S5 ? from a certain network providers.

Comment: Consult your carrier - this is not something you can do by flashing stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Unlocking refers to the bootloader. Its a necessary step if you want to flash the firmware of your device. Refer to the XDA forums and search for your device. There are a lot of How-To's that might help you.

Comment: It's not very wise to tell a user who came to a Q&A site for help to "go search yourself" without much clues.